# Discharged battery on bike, should it be replaced?

Tags: battery, motorcycle

So my bike was sitting idle for over a year in a different state since I moved back to my hometown due to covid. Unfortunately, my friend doesn't know how to operate a bike so there was no way for someone to start it to keep the battery charged up during this time. I have an aftermarket GPS tool on my bike which is connected to the main battery source. Last month I got a notification that my bike battery is completely dead since the GPS device lost its power.

I had a talk with one of the local mechanics and he told me that since my bike battery is dead, I need to replace my battery with the new one. I am a bit sceptical since my bike was barely a year old since I left it last year.

Now if a battery is completely discharged, do I have to buy a new one or just get it recharged somehow(probably by starting the bike and let it recharge)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try recharging it before you use it, but don't use the bike to do it. Use a regular battery charger. The bike isn't designed to recharge the battery but basically to maintain it plus the little bit of juice the bike will use up during starting. If the battery will recharge, then all is good. If it doesn't, you'll need to replace it. Note, however, leaving the battery to be fully discharged will have damaged the battery and will cause a shortened lifespan. How long that is, nobody knows. Bottom line, I wouldn't just replace the battery before trying to recover the old one.